# Efficient method to convert a vector to a row in Mat or empty Mat in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Assume that Mat is empty or Mat has the same structure of coloumns with a vector, is there any efficient method to convert a vector directly into Mat as one single row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a constructor of Mat:

```
C++: template<typename T> explicitMat::Mat(const vector<T>& vec, bool copyData=false)
```

You can have a try.

Comment: It works. Two more points for attention: 1) the Mat structure is nx1; 2) be careful about the data property for the Mat. CV_32FC1 or CV_64F. it is better to use "convertTo" to maintain the data property consistence.

Comment: It works. Two more points for attention: 1) the Mat structure is nx1; 2) be careful about the data property for the Mat. CV_32FC1 or CV_64F. it is better to use "convertTo"  to maintain the data property consistence.